# Add a contextual menu that add text to an input

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make this code to work to no avail. I want it to work this way, the user right click on the input and whatever he selects will be added to the input.

```
$(document).bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e.pageX + "," + e.pageY);
  $("#cntnr").css("left", e.pageX);
  $("#cntnr").css("top", e.pageY);
  // $("#cntnr").hide(100);        
  $("#cntnr").fadeIn(200, startFocusOut());
});

function startFocusOut() {
  $(document).on("click", function() {
    $("#cntnr").hide();
    $(document).off("click");
  });
}

$("#items > li").click(function() {
  $("#op").text("You have selected " + $(this).text());
});
```

Here is the Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/6ny94/1226/

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiddled with your code a bit, try this;

Update the HTML:

```
Demo<input id="op"></input>
  <div id='cntnr'>
    <ul id='items'>
      <li class="mitem">Copy</li> 
      <li class="mitem">paste</li> 
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Update the JS:

```
$(document).bind("contextmenu",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e.pageX + "," + e.pageY);
  $("#cntnr").css("left",e.pageX);
  $("#cntnr").css("top",e.pageY);
 // $("#cntnr").hide(100);        
  $("#cntnr").fadeIn(200,startFocusOut());      
});

function startFocusOut(){
  $(document).on("click",function(){
  $("#cntnr").hide();        
  $(document).off("click");
  });
}

$(".mitem").click(function(){
$("#op").val("You have selected "+$(this).text());
});
```

Basically whatever is selected from the context menu updates the value of the input box; you previously also setted OP's text, not val; that could've been the issue. I just added a class selector and used that to push the value into the input.

Comment: Thank you, it works great, but the right click is still firing if I click outside the input. Is there a way to make it work only on the input?

Comment: Change $(document).bind("contextmenu",function(e){ to $("#op").bind("contextmenu",function(e){

Comment: Your currently binding contextmenu to the whole document, just mod the selector from document to the input box and you should be good; will only appear on input

Comment: Yeah it worked, but the menu is still displaying after the click.

Comment: $("#op").on and $("#op").bind instead of $("document").bind in your function both worked ok for me; I just ran the fiddle and seems to be working fine as it automatically pastes the menu item data into the inputbox. If you see the contextmenu on your input after you've clicked an item you can add $("#cntnr").hide(); after $("#op").val("You have selected "+$(this).text()); to trigger hiding it; tho on Chrome it seems good to go as is; give it a try

Answer (score 1):

A very slight change: an `input` has a value... Not a `text`.

So `$("#op").val(...)` instead of `$("#op").text(...)`.

And [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) is deprecated. Use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```js
$("#op").on("contextmenu",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e.pageX + "," + e.pageY);
  $("#cntnr").css("left",e.pageX);
  $("#cntnr").css("top",e.pageY);
 // $("#cntnr").hide(100);        
  $("#cntnr").fadeIn(200,startFocusOut());      
});

function startFocusOut(){
  $(document).on("click",function(){
  $("#cntnr").hide();        
  $(document).off("click");
  });
}

$("#items > li").click(function(){
$("#op").val("You have selected "+$(this).text());
});
```

```css
#items{
  list-style:none;
  margin:0px;
  margin-top:4px;
  padding-left:10px;
  padding-right:10px;
  padding-bottom:3px;
  font-size:17px;
  color: #333333;
  
}
hr { width: 85%; 
  background-color:#E4E4E4;
  border-color:#E4E4E4;
    color:#E4E4E4;
}
#cntnr{
  display:none;
  position:fixed;
  border:1px solid #B2B2B2;
  width:150px;      background:#F9F9F9;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px #E9E9E9;
  border-radius:4px;
}

li{
  
  padding: 3px;
  padding-left:10px;
}


#items :hover{
   color: white;
  background:#284570;
  border-radius:2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Demo<input id="op">
<div id='cntnr'>
  <ul id='items'>
    <li>Copy</li> 
    <li>paste</li> 
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: it works great, but the right click is still firing if I click outside the input. The answer below solved it, but the menu is still visible after the click?

Comment: Well... Just change `document` for `"#op"` then... I edited.

Comment: My pleasure buddy ;)